# Being denied access to my usb drive in console mode

Tags: usb, terminal, permissions

I am trying to access the usb stick that I use for storage on my Pi, `PI_USB`. I am able to access it while using `startx`, but I am denied permission while in console mode.

In the terminal, I typed in the following:

```
$ cd /media
/media $ cd PI_USB
bash: Permission Denied
/media $ sudo cd PI_USB
sudo: cd: command not found
```

I was wondering, why am I being denied permission? How can I fix this? I am using the `byobu` console interface, could this be the issue?

Comment: What is mounting the device?

Comment: Indeed. Do you mount it yourself, or automatically? What does your /etc/fstab contain?

Comment: @Jivings How would I find out what mounts it? I use an external USB port (from staples...)

Comment: I mean are you mounting it yourself? Can you access as root (not using `sudo`).

Comment: you can not sudo cd but you can start a new shell with 
sudo -s 
and then running cd would do so with root access. Remember to type exit before doing anything that could wreck your system.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and I ended to start doing :

```
sudo chmod 777 PI_USB
```

As a workaround before putting the good permissions.

Good luck!

Comment: While not very elegant, it does solve the problem. I'll upvote.